# Как обойти проблему асинхронного кода в Swift?

Tags: swift, асинхронность, alamofire

В теории я понимаю как это работает. Но на практике с такими проблемами не встречался.
Какое решение может мне помочь в данной ситуации?

```swift
class ToDoNetworking {

    var getData: [ToDo] {
        fetchToDos()
    }

    func fetchToDos() -> [ToDo] {
        print("START")
        var returnArr: [ToDo] = []

        let request = Session.default.request("http://localhost:3003/")

        request.responseDecodable(of: ToDos.self) { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let tasks):
                returnArr = tasks.items
                print("FILLED UP")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("FAILED to FETCH JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        print("END")
        return returnArr
    }
 
}
```

> **console**:

```
START
END
FILLED UP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам можно использовать здесь completion handler

```
class ToDoNetworking {
    
    typealias DataCompletionHandler = ([ToDo]) -> Void

    func getData(_ completionHandler: DataCompletionHandler) {
        fetchToDos { result in
            completionHandler(result)
        }
    }

    func fetchToDos(_ completionHandler: DataCompletionHandler) {
        print("START")
        var returnArr: [ToDo] = []

        let request = Session.default.request("http://localhost:3003/")

        request.responseDecodable(of: ToDos.self) { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let tasks):
                returnArr = tasks.items
                completionHandler(returnArr)
                print("FILLED UP")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("FAILED to FETCH JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        print("END")
    }
 
}
```